# OneDrive client on Windows 8.1 is unable to download Office docs correctly

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

I'm having strange problems with OneDrive starting Aug 27. Built-in OneDrive client on Windows 8.1 is unable to download Office docs from the cloud correctly.

Sometimes these files appear on local system as XML documents, which contain some information from original doc (I would say that these XML files look like data for "smart preview" or something like this). And sometimes these files appear as just a small part of the original document. Of course, in both cases Office Apps are unable to open these files.

OneDrive client reports that these files have "Problem downloading" but doesn't show any details. These files are still accessible thru OneDrive web UI, I can download them from web and they are the same as original files. Moreover, which is important I think, this problem affects Office documents ONLY. PDFs, pictures, archives and special files (e.g. KeePass database) are synchronizing without any issues.

I'm wondering if anybody knows what the root cause of this problem is and how to fix it?

BTW, I'm not the only one who has this problem. The following thread contains some interesting information: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/sdfiles-sdsync/onedrive-is-corrupting-files/01aefba7-1750-4fbf-a9f2-028b2615e8ee

Additional info:

1. The problem exists on two computers with Windows 8.1.
2. OneDrive 6.3.9600.17230, OneDrive app 6.3.9600.17122, Sync engine 6.3.9600.17230
3. I have Office 2013 installed on both computers.
4. I also have OneDrive Pro client installed on both computers (BTW, I've tried to disable OneDrive Pro on one computer, it did not help).
5. First time I saw this problem when synchronizing Word 2007 document, which was created on Win7, to Win 8.1. However, I found that this problem also affects Office 2013 documents and Win 8 to Win 8 synchronization.

Comment: What version of office?

Comment: Office 2007 on Windows 7 and Office 2013 on Windows 8.

Comment: .doc or .docx files?

Comment: .docx and .xslx

Comment: BTW, I'm not the only one who has this problem: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/sdfiles-sdsync/onedrive-is-corrupting-files/01aefba7-1750-4fbf-a9f2-028b2615e8ee

Comment: It started happening to me too

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same problem.

I managed to get a Microsoft online tech rep to investigate the issue today. He worked 5 hours straight remotely on my computers (a mix of several Win8.1 clients experiencing above Office 2013 document corruption, some Win7 clients working ok all the time), attempted every imaginable problem solving approach but could not find a way to fix it. It is a weird problem since it affects only the most central Office document formats - everything else syncs fine.

As it stands now, Office documents become corrupted when synced to (some?) Win8.1 users from OneDrive, and the MS tech support rep. promised to escalate the issue.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a fix for this currently.

Comment: Well, I hope MS will fix this problem soon.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like the problem has been solved: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/sdfiles-sdopen/onedrive-excel-files-not-valid-corrupted/ca93eb16-72dd-41ea-8704-2f440c4a9281?page=5